How would you write this?
"If i didnt think she was good for the job,i wouldnt ask you to hire her."
I feel like the sentence above is awkwardly formed. How would you write it?

Where is the apostrophe (‘) sign?

The substance of the sentence is fine, assuming it matches what you are saying. Note that there are several punctuation errors.

swmcdonnell is right on the money :) 'Good' is as vacuous as 'nice' or other lukewarm words. 'Right' implies confidence.

General writing advice is off-topic here. If there's something in particular about the sentence that you're concerned about, please use the "Edit" button to explain more and it can be addressed.

I'll give a custom reason for my vote to close, as several are represented here: "How would you write it" invites opinion-based answers; a "find errors" question without a clear area of concern falls under "proofreading"; and in general "awkwardly formed" is vague, and the question "needs details and clarity."

The structure of the sentence is also not "awkwardly formed".  People could disagree over the aptness of "good" vs "right". I think "right" is better but there are plenty of attestations of "good for the job" including sites giving advice to job applicants.

Don't forget to upvote answer(s) that helped you the most. Click on the arrow pointing up

Asking users to fix errors is off-topic on ELL, it comes under the term proof-reading. I also find your silence in the comment section to be quite rude.

You're missing some punctuation, but I think your question is about using the word good.
A person really can't be good for a job, but a person can be a good match or a good fit for a job. If you're looking for a single word that conveys this, the best word would be right
So any of these work:

If I didn't think she was right for the job, I wouldn't ask you to hire her.
If I didn't think she was a good match for the job...
If I didn't think she was a good fit for the job...


The following sentence

If I didnt think she was good for the job, I wouldnt ask you to hire her.

is arguing the case from a defensive position, either reactively or proactively, as evident in the negative construction: "If I didn't think..."
Consider the following conversation where the recommendation is replied to with a bit of push-back:

I think you should hire her.
-- Do you really think she will fit in here?
If I didnt think she was good for the job, I wouldnt ask you to hire her.

The person recommending her is reacting to the push-back.
But a person who is recommending someone in writing (not in a live conversation) might anticipate some push-back, and thus write such a thing proactively.

I would like you to hire her. I expect that with her prison record you might think she is not an appropriate hire, but if I didn't think she was good for the job, I wouldn't ask you to hire her.  She was barely 18 at the time, and lived in a state where possession of a relatively small amount of marijuana was a felony.  She has a very good eye, and the advertizing agency would do well to hire a photographer with her skills.

